# Tuple in Javascript

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'd like to send a transaction to a smart contract (token swap).
https://ftmscan.com/address/0xa38cd27185a464914d3046f0ab9d43356b34829d#code

The smart contract requires an additional boolean value next to the addresses:

> Function: swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256, uint256,
> (address,address,bool)[], address, uint256)

when I send

> const txObject = {
> nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
> gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(350000),
> gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(gas, "Gwei")),
> to: contractAddress,
> data: contract.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(web3.utils.toHex(from_amt), web3.utils.toHex(to_amt),['0x04068DA6C83AFCFA0e13ba15A6696662335D5B75','0xE55e19Fb4F2D85af758950957714292DAC1e25B2',false], address, web3.utils.toHex(deadline)).encodeABI(),       chainId: web3.utils.toHex(chain_id)     }

I get the error message

> reason: 'invalid tuple value',
> code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
> argument: 'tuple',
> value: '0x04068DA6C83AFCFA0e13ba15A6696662335D5B75'

How to format this tuple correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In solidity tuple always pass in [] bracket. For your function input format is

(uint256,uint256,[["address","address",bool]],"address",uint256).

should check the format carefully, especially nested tuple in list

Comment: I did that. I get "Error: invalid tuple value"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this test in Web3 playground](https://web3playground.io/QmYpixnzXVs2g6LBwboQJVnbBW8Duw8Tb8PD9gAghtUMnh), wrapping your array in additional array should work:

```js
const txObject = {
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(350000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(gas, "Gwei")),
  to: contractAddress,
  data: contract.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    web3.utils.toHex(from_amt), 
    web3.utils.toHex(to_amt), 
    [
      [
        '0x04068DA6C83AFCFA0e13ba15A6696662335D5B75',
        '0xE55e19Fb4F2D85af758950957714292DAC1e25B2',
        false,
      ],
    ],
    address,
    web3.utils.toHex(deadline)
  ).encodeABI(),
  chainId: web3.utils.toHex(chain_id)
}
```